# Multiplayer glitching in smallbasic

Tags: multiplayer, smallbasic

I've been working on a Multiplayer game (again) and I've got a problem with glitching.

If you Start it up and join the server on two Computers, you will notice that the ships will kind of glitch around a bit. I think this is due to the messages sent being received at irregular times and the ships getting updated before they are in the right position.

I need help figuring out the solution to it! Thanks!

http://www.mediafire.com/download/xf7ez07dxmh0hq3/Multiplayer_start.zip

Here is the code:

Server:

```
TextWindow.Write("Enter the Port to host on:")
Port = TextWindow.Read()
TextWindow.WriteLine(IOTCPServer.StartServer(Port))

IOTCPServer.OnClientConnect = OnClientConnect
IOTCPServer.OnMessageRecieved = OnMessageRecieved

Timer.Tick = SendClientnumbers
Timer.Interval = 1000
Sub OnClientConnect
NumClients = NumClients + 1
Clients = IOTCPServer.GetClients()
Info["Type"] = "Cc"
Info["Info"] = Clients
 TextWindow.WriteLine(Info)
  For i = 1 To Array.GetItemCount(Clients)
  IOTCPServer.SendMessage(Info,Clients[i])
  EndFor
EndSub

Sub OnMessageRecieved
For i = 1 To NumClients
  IOTCPServer.SendMessage(IOTCPServer.LastMessageData,Clients[i-1])
  EndFor
EndSub

Sub SendClientnumbers
  For u = 1 To NumClients
    Info2["T"] = "N"
    Info2["UN"] = u
    IOTCPServer.SendMessage(Info2,Clients[u-1])
    EndFor
  EndSub
```

---

Client:

```
GraphicsWindow.Width = 800
GraphicsWindow.Height = 600
TextWindow.Write("Enter the port: ")
Port = TextWindow.Read()
TextWindow.Write("Enter the IP: ")
ServIp = TextWindow.Read()
TextWindow.Hide()
IOTCPClient.Connect(ServIp,Port)
IOTCPClient.OnMessageRecieved = OnMessageRecieved

Ip = IOTCPClient.IP

NumOfShips = 3




For i = 1 to NumOfShips
Ship[i] = Shapes.AddImage(Program.Directory + "/Ship1.png")
Shipx[i] = GraphicsWindow.Width / 2
Shipy[i] = GraphicsWindow.Height - 200
ShipMass[i] = 5
ShipF[i] = 0
ShipRotForce[i] = 1500
ElapsedMill[i] = Clock.ElapsedMilliseconds
EndFor

GraphicsWindow.DrawImage(Program.Directory + "/Space.jpg",0,-50)

Keybind[1] = "Up"
Keybind[2] = "Down"
Keybind[3] = "Right"
Keybind[4] = "Left"
Keybind[5] = "Space"

For KeyUpNum = 1 To 4
  Key[KeyUpNum] = "Up"
EndFor

'UserNum = 1



GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = OnKeyDown
GraphicsWindow.KeyUp = OnKeyUp

While UserNum = "" 
Program.Delay(100)
Time = Time + 100
If Time > 5000 Then
GraphicsWindow.ShowMessage("Could not get reply from host at: "+ServIp+":"+Port,"")
Program.Delay(1000)
Program.End()
EndIf
EndWhile



While 1 = 1 
Program.Delay(5)
'TextWindow.Clear()
For i = 1 To NumOfShips




TimeElapsed[i] = (Clock.ElapsedMilliseconds - ElapsedMill[i]) / 1000
ElapsedMill[i] = Clock.ElapsedMilliseconds

ShipAccel[i] = (ShipF[i]/ShipMass[i]) 
AngleAccel[i] = (AngleF[i]/ShipMass[i]) 

VelocityX[i] = VelocityX[i] + ((ShipAccel[i] * TimeElapsed[i]) *           Math.Cos(Math.GetRadians(Angle[i]+90))) '<--- Find the Horizontal (X) Velocity
VelocityY[i] = VelocityY[i] + ((ShipAccel[i] * TimeElapsed[i]) *     Math.Sin(Math.GetRadians(Angle[i]+90))) '<--- Find the Vertical (Y) Velocity
AngleVel[i] = AngleVel[i] + (AngleAccel[i] * TimeElapsed[i])

Shipx[i] = Shipx[i] + (VelocityX[i] * TimeElapsed[i])
Shipy[i] = Shipy[i] + (VelocityY[i] * TimeElapsed[i])
Angle[i] = Angle[i] + (AngleVel[i] * TimeElapsed[i])



Shapes.Move(Ship[i],Shipx[i],Shipy[i])
Shapes.Rotate(Ship[i],Angle[i])

EndFor

CheckKeyStrokes()
EndWhile

Sub OnKeyDown
For KeydownNum = 1 To Array.GetItemCount(Keybind)
If GraphicsWindow.LastKey = Keybind[KeydownNum] Then
  Key[KeydownNum] = "Down"
EndIf
EndFor
EndSub

Sub OnKeyUp
For KeyUpNum = 1 To Array.GetItemCount(Keybind)
If GraphicsWindow.LastKey = Keybind[KeyUpNum] Then
  Key[KeyUpNum] = "Up"
EndIf
EndFor
EndSub

Sub CheckKeyStrokes
If Key[3] = "Down" And AngleF[UserNum] <> ShipRotForce[UserNum] Then
AngleF[UserNum] = ShipRotForce[UserNum]
ForceChange()
EndIf
If Key[4] = "Down" And AngleF[UserNum] <> -ShipRotForce[UserNum] Then
AngleF[UserNum] = -ShipRotForce[UserNum]
ForceChange()
EndIf
If Key[3] = "Up" And Key[4] = "Up" And AngleF[UserNum] <> 0 Then
AngleF[UserNum] = 0
ForceChange()
EndIf
If Key[2] = "Down" And ShipF[UserNum] <> 1500 Then
ShipF[UserNum] = 1500
ForceChange()
EndIf
If Key[1] = "Down" And ShipF[UserNum] <> -1500 Then
ShipF[UserNum] = -1500
ForceChange()
EndIf
If Key[1] = "Up" And Key[2] = "Up" And ShipF[UserNum] <> 0 Then
ShipF[UserNum] = 0
ForceChange()
EndIf

If Key[5] = "Down" Then
TextWindow.WriteLine("Checking...")
SendServerCheck()
EndIf
EndSub

Sub ForceChange

If Angle[UserNum] > 360 Then
Angle[UserNum] = Angle[UserNum] - 360
EndIf
If Angle[UserNum] < 0 Then
Angle[UserNum] = Angle[UserNum] + 360
EndIf

Position["x"] = Math.Round(Shipx[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Position["y"] = Math.Round(Shipy[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["T"] = "FU" 'Type
Info["N"] = UserNum 'Num
Info["P"] = Position
Info["VX"] = Math.Round(VelocityX[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["VY"] = Math.Round(VelocityY[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["A"] = Math.Round(Angle[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["AV"] = Math.Round(AngleVel[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["F"] = Math.Round(ShipF[UserNum]*10000)/10000 'Force
Info["N"] = UserNum 'Num
Info["AF"] = Math.Round(AngleF[UserNum]*10000)/10000 ' Angle
IOTCPClient.SendMessage(Info)
EndSub



Sub OnMessageRecieved
RecInfo = IOTCPClient.LastMessageData

If RecInfo["T"] = "N" Then
UserNum = RecInfo["UN"]
EndIf

If RecInfo["N"] <> UserNum Then



If RecInfo["T"] = "FU" Then
  Pos = RecInfo["P"]
  Shipx[RecInfo["N"]] = Pos["x"]
  Shipy[RecInfo["N"]] = Pos["y"]
  VelocityX[RecInfo["N"]] = RecInfo["VX"]
  VelocityY[RecInfo["N"]] = RecInfo["VY"]
  Angle[RecInfo["N"]] = RecInfo["A"]
  AngleVel[RecInfo["N"]] = RecInfo["AV"]
  ShipF[RecInfo["N"]] = RecInfo["F"]
  AngleF[RecInfo["N"]] = RecInfo["AF"]
EndIf
EndIf



If RecInfo["T"] = "CH" Then
If RecInfo["N"] = UserNum Then
TextWindow.WriteLine("Connected to Server!!!")
EndIf
EndIF

EndSub

Sub SendServerCheck
Info["T"] = "CH"
IOTCPClient.SendMessage(Info)
EndSub


Sub SendPosInfo
Position["x"] = Math.Round(Shipx[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Position["y"] = Math.Round(Shipy[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["T"] = "PU" 'Type
Info["N"] = UserNum 'Num
Info["P"] = Position
Info["VX"] = Math.Round(VelocityX[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["VY"] = Math.Round(VelocityY[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["A"] = Math.Round(Angle[UserNum]*10000)/10000
Info["AV"] = Math.Round(AngleVel[UserNum]*10000)/10000
IOTCPClient.SendMessage(Info)
EndSub
```

Comment: You may want to look into the idea of network synchronization. You need to enforce some form of order onto your packets so you are not applying earlier updates after later ones.

Comment: Hmm. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: I would suggest something like Laports clocks but I'm sure there are libraries out there to support it

Comment: I would like to give you some help.. What extension is this? does it work with v1.2?

Comment: I got it figured out back in '14 by using the 'Litdev' extension: http://litdev.co.uk/
Thanks tho!